# Sychronous wrapper around UIApplication.openURL:options:completion:

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am deprecating iOS 9 on a project. One of the differences in the framework is that the openURL method has changed.

**iOS 9**

`- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url;`

**iOS 10**

`- (void)openURL:(NSURL *)url 
         options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options 
completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL success))completion;`

Notice how the method changed from being synchronous to asynchronous.

Since I have a bunch of usages for the synchronous method, I want to create a synchronous wrapper around the asynchronous `openURL:options:completion:` method and I'm going to update the usages to call this asynchronous wrapper instead.

My first attempt looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)sync_openURL: (nullable NSURL *)url {
    __block BOOL result = nil;
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    [self openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        result = success;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];
    while (dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW)) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is this a good replacement ? Can it be improved in anyway ?

Comment: Why don't you want to make your code asynchronous?

Answer (score 2):

That code should work, but blocking the main thread is never a good idea. That's why the method was changed in the first place.

I suggest a deeper refactor of your code so that you use the new async method with completion handler as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special here.
Just change to the new method and ignore the completion handler.

```
[application openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```